# Insufficient privileges when deleting

Tags: java, oracle, spring-batch, sql-delete, dml

I have s spring-batch application.

The tests fail somehow with the following error :

```
2019-04-26 09:54:56 ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step stepCleanTrades in job tradesLoadJob
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE (SELECT F.*, T.* FROM T_TRADE T JOIN T_CASH_FLOW F ON F.TRADE_ID = T.ID JOIN T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM S ON S.ID = T.UP_SYS_ID WHERE trunc(T.RECORD_DATE) = trunc(?) AND S.NAME = ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:866) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:890) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:292) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at com.bank.dept.app.batch.dao.impl.TradesDaoImpl.deleteCurrentTrades(TradesDaoImpl.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
at com.bank.dept.app.batch.tasklet.CleanCurrentTradesTasklet.execute(CleanCurrentTradesTasklet.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at $Proxy66.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at $Proxy32.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:152) [spring-batch-test-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:141) [spring-batch-test-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at com.bank.dept.app.dml.cc.test.IntegrationExistingMessageTest.launchAllSteps(IntegrationExistingMessageTest.java:144) [test-classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) [spring-test-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) [spring-test-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) [spring-test-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254) [spring-test-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:873) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:866) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
... 83 common frames omitted
```

The job is defined by :

```
<beans:bean id="cleanCurrentTradesTasklet"
    class="com.bank.dept.app.batch.tasklet.CleanCurrentTradesTasklet" scope="step">
</beans:bean>

<batch:job id="tradesLoadJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <batch:step id="stepCleanTrades" >
        <batch:tasklet ref="cleanCurrentTradesTasklet" allow-start-if-complete="true" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The job class :

```
public class CleanCurrentTradesTasklet implements Tasklet {
    @Autowired
    TradesDao tradesDao;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1) throws Exception {
        tradesDao.deleteCurrentTrades();
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

The test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:app-dml-subscriber-top-level-test.xml" })
@ActiveProfiles(profiles={"local","notification-no-ssl","no-stock"})
public class IntegrationExistingMessageTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void launchAllSteps() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());
    }
}
```

The dao class :

```
@Repository("tradesDao")
public class TradesDaoImpl implements TradesDao {

    private static final String UPSTREAM_SYSTEM = "GCAL";

    private static final String DELETE_CURRENT_TRADES = "DELETE (SELECT F.*, T.* FROM T_TRADE T JOIN T_CASH_FLOW F ON F.TRADE_ID = T.ID JOIN T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM S ON S.ID = T.UP_SYS_ID WHERE trunc(T.RECORD_DATE) = trunc(:date) AND S.NAME = :upstream)";

    private static final String DELETE_TEST = "DELETE (SELECT F.*, T.* FROM T_TRADE T JOIN T_CASH_FLOW F ON F.TRADE_ID = T.ID WHERE trunc(T.RECORD_DATE) = trunc(:date) AND T.SYS_REF = 'DH1910800009')";

    @Override
    public void deleteCurrentTrades() {
        Date today = new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(2);
        params.put("date", today);
        params.put("upstream", UPSTREAM_SYSTEM);
        this.getJdbcTemplate().update(DELETE_CURRENT_TRADES, params);
    }
}
```

My goal here is to delete data from T_TRADE and T_CASH_FLOW tables

When I change deleteCurrentTrades() to the code below, I don't have the exception :

```
@Override
public void deleteCurrentTrades() {
    Date today = new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(1);
    params.put("date", today);
    this.getJdbcTemplate().update(DELETE_TEST, params);
}
```

It seems the problem lies with the grants on the T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM table, which are below :

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
| Privilege |     Grantee      | Grantable |  Grantor  |    Object Name    |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
| SELECT    | APP_MONITORING   | NO        | APP_OWNER | T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM |
| SELECT    | APP_CONSULT      | NO        | APP_OWNER | T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM |
| SELECT    | APP_WAS          | NO        | APP_OWNER | T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM |
| SELECT    | BATCH_USER       | NO        | APP_OWNER | T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM |
| SELECT    | APP_FR_USER      | NO        | APP_OWNER | T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM |
| SELECT    | APP_CONSULT_LVL3 | NO        | APP_OWNER | T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

The user used is BATCH_USER

What is wrong with my query ?

Comment: If you want to delete from a table, the database schema doing the deletion needs to have the DELETE privilege on the table. In other words, get the schema that owns the table to grant delete to the relevant schema.

Comment: But the query doesn't delete from T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM, why would the schema need the DELETE privilege ?

Comment: I don't know where you got that table from; it'll be one (or both) of the tables in the delete statement mentioned in the original error message that is missing the delete privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `T_TRADE` and `T_CASH_FLOW` are tables of `BATCH_USER` schema, and `T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM` is a table of `APP_OWNER`

Provided you have granted ( `SQL> conn APP_OWNER SQL> grant delete on T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM to BATCH_USER` ) the delete privilege to the `BATCH_USER`, you can delete the desired records through :

```
DELETE APP_OWNER.T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM SS
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM T_TRADE T
                 JOIN T_CASH_FLOW F
                   ON F.TRADE_ID = T.ID
                 JOIN APP_OWNER.T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM S
                   ON S.ID = T.UP_SYS_ID
                WHERE trunc(T.RECORD_DATE) = trunc(?)
                  AND S.NAME = ?
                  AND S.ID = SS.ID );
```

with schema name `APP_OWNER.` prefixed for `T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM`.

**Edit :** *( I forgot the point you wanted to to delete from other tables than the one above I mentioned )*. So, use the following seperate delete statements :

```
DELETE T_TRADE TT
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM T_TRADE T
                 JOIN T_CASH_FLOW F
                   ON F.TRADE_ID = T.ID
                 JOIN APP_OWNER.T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM S
                   ON S.ID = T.UP_SYS_ID
                WHERE trunc(T.RECORD_DATE) = trunc(?)
                  AND S.NAME = ?
                  AND T.ID = TT.ID );

DELETE T_CASH_FLOW FF
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM T_TRADE T
                 JOIN T_CASH_FLOW F
                   ON F.TRADE_ID = T.ID
                 JOIN APP_OWNER.T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM S
                   ON S.ID = T.UP_SYS_ID
                WHERE trunc(T.RECORD_DATE) = trunc(?)
                  AND S.NAME = ?
                  AND F.TRADE_ID = FF.TRADE_ID );
```

Comment: But I don't want to delete from T_UPSTREAM_SYSTEM, and in fact the query DOESN'T delete from that table when run directly through Oracle SQL developer.

Comment: @l0r3nz4cc10 then seems you need to explain more about what you'd like

Comment: Quote from my question : 'My goal here is to delete data from T_TRADE and T_CASH_FLOW tables'

Comment: @l0r3nz4cc10 excuse me, I missed that sentence, edited now.